# Have wordpress add to existing external RSS feed when publishing

Tags: wordpress, rss, publish

I have a RSS feed in an XML file at the root level. I have a php script that adds to the xml when ever i want to add to it. Is there a way to have wordpress add to that RSS feed every-time publish a blog post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, that'd be no problem so long as you can parse the XML and then append nodes to it (XML docs are not as straight forward as, say, doing a `file_put_contents()` to append to the doc).

One way to do this would be to [hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) onto the [`edit_post`](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/edit_post) action and do your update in the callback function.

Comment: See the post above. 1) Write a function 2) hook onto edit_post 3) update your file on callback.